# Change image size of cell image in static table

Tags: ios, uitableview

[image]

I've created this entire menu using the static table, no code so far for this. But I want to manipulate 2 things.

1. I want to control image height & width present in each cell. As shown above.
2. Need to change x position of "Accessory" present in every cell.(Refer reference image 2)

[image]

As you can see the menu is hiding all my accessories. Reducing TableView width would make another issue of the black bar as shown in below image.

[image]

Storyboard approach is appreciated. Or few lines of code. But don't recommend me to make entire TableView using code.

Employing custom cell you can solve the problem, but you have to create image, label & accessory, which were given complimentary with default cell. So if it is not possible then prove it otherwise provide a solution.

Comment: create custom cell...or for images you can resize it and use it.

Answer (score 1):

Q1: I want to control image height & width

A: Initially check your tableviewCell type as **Custom** or not, if its not **custom** change the cell type to custom, and  you want the fixed width and height then change the following lines in storyboard

```
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.contentMode =.scaleAspectFit
```

Q2: Need to change x position of "Accessory" present in every cell.(Refer reference image 2)

A: on your rearView change the width of tableview (not a fullscreen width use fullscreenwidth - 30 )

if your rear view as a tableviewcontroller then change the frame in viewWillAppear or ViewDidAppear

```
  func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super. viewDidAppear(animated)
    tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: yourYPosition, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 30, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

}
```

Comment: thanks Sir, but table view height width is uneditable

Comment: @RAISIQBAL - its a viewcontroller with UItableview or UItableviewController

Comment: UITable view controller

Comment: As you suggested for the image. It is already set as you said, but where are the options to change height width?

Comment: @RAISIQBAL - image content mode use aspectFIt and checkonce

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167867/discussion-between-rais-iqbal-and-anbu-karthik).

Comment: @Anbu.kathik Your help really appreciated. Part of your answers worked. Also, your suggestion to use custom cell worked for me. 


But am still not accepting this answer. So that let people dig it & for future, we may get different approaches & as you and me seen there no way to change the size of static cell image. So that devs can raise this to Apple. Thanks alot for your help